# Save number or a string in json column without having to specify a key? Is this possbile?

Tags: mysql, json

Is it possible to store just a single number inside a json column in MySQL?

For example when I try to validate if this is a valid json

```
{55}
```

I get an error saying that this is not valid json.

How do I save a string or a number inside the json column without any key? I just want to store the value itself. Is this even possible?

Comment: Single element array? `[
  55
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a string representation of the number e.g.

```
create table test (j json);
insert into test values ('55');
select * from test
```

Output

```
55
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fcc41877441c65b9148ee8ee052a015b)

Comment: you are right, since RFC7159 you can insert a single value without a key. I just tested it in my project as well after your example code above, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the key equal to the value, for example - {"55":55}
or as suggested @lukasz-szozda use array type.
But you can’t exactly insert a keyless value(because of JSON standard )

Comment: This is not true. From the (standard)[https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159]: "JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays)"

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the string representation of the number like:

```
insert into test (json_column) values ('55');
```

While

```
insert into test (json_column) values (55);
```

will fail raising an "Invalid JSON" error.

If you have the number stored in a variable, you will need to cast it to JSON or a valid JSON string. Assuming your number is stored in a user variable:

```
set @v = 55;
```

Then

```
insert into test (json_column) values (@v);
```

will fail.

But any of the following will work:

```
insert into test (json_column) values (cast(@v as json));
insert into test (json_column) values (cast(@v as char));
insert into test (json_column) values (concat(@v));
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to create a column of type `JSON`
Then try to insert a value into that column, It will save as what you want.

eg:-

```
Create table query
create table my_json_table(val json);


Insert table query
insert into my_json_table (val) values ('55');
```

Please try this way. It will help you.